# How to generate the right password format for Apache2 authentication in use with DBD and MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication, apache2, mod-auth

I want to authenticate users for a folder from a MySQL 5.1 database with `AuthType Basic`.
The passwords are stored in plain text (they are not really passwords, so doesn't matter).
The password format for apache however only allows for SHA1, MD5 on Linux systems [as described here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html).

How could I generate the right format with an SQL query ? Seems like apache format is a binary format with a lenght of 20, but the mysql `SHA1` function return 40 long.

My SQL query is something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('{SHA}', BASE64_ENCODE(SHA1(access_key))) FROM user_access_keys INNER JOIN users ON user_access_keys.user_id = users.id WHERE name = %s
```

where `base64_encode` is a stored function (Mysql 5.1 doesn't have `TO_BASE64` yet). This query returns a 61 byte BLOB which is not the same format that apache uses. How could I generate the same format ?

You can suggest other method for this too. The point is that I want to authenticate users from a MySQL5.1 database using plain text as password.

Comment: ok, so how do I generate the right format with SQL query using that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you refer to does not mean to imply non-Linux by "Unix-only", therefore crypt() is available to you. Since you seem unconcerned about security I'd suggest this is the easiest option alongside MySQL's [encrypt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html) function. You may want to use a constant seed value in your queries.

```
SELECT ENCRYPT(access_key, 'SA') FROM user_access_keys INNER JOIN users ON user_access_keys.user_id = users.id WHERE name = %s
```